# error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libtargad.lib'

Tags: visual-c++

I'm using visual studio 2010 - c#
when trying to run a free source code I've just downloaded - it says:
error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libtargad.lib' 
the free source is Wolf3D and is using the Targa lib...
anyone knows where I can get this LIB file ?

Comment: I really doubt this has anything to do with C#.